# Keras InvalidArgumentError in first convolutional block of UNET with 2 channel image

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train a 2D UNET convolutional network with a (256,256,2) input to predict an output of the same dimensions. I've been having some issues with preparing the training data for loading which I though was the problem, but the model summary tells me the error occurs in the first convolutional layer. All filters are (3,3). How can I fix this issue?

I considered that I might need to use 3D layers instead of 2D, but I've seen tutorials that use RGB images with 2D convolutional layers, so I don't think this is the issue.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 3 vs 2
     [[node model_7/conv2d_105/BiasAdd (defined at <ipython-input-9-957db582cfa0>:171) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_19507]
```

Architecture

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_8 (InputLayer)            [(None, 256, 256, 2) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_105 (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 16) 304         input_8[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_98 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_105[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_98 (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 16) 0           batch_normalization_98[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_106 (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 16) 2320        activation_98[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_99 (BatchNo (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_106[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_99 (Activation)      (None, 256, 256, 16) 0           batch_normalization_99[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_21 (AveragePo (None, 128, 128, 16) 0           activation_99[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_107 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 32) 4640        average_pooling2d_21[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_100 (BatchN (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_107[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_100 (Activation)     (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_100[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_108 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        activation_100[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_101 (BatchN (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_108[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_101 (Activation)     (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_101[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_22 (AveragePo (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           activation_101[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_109 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   18496       average_pooling2d_22[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_102 (BatchN (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_109[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_102 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           batch_normalization_102[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_110 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       activation_102[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_103 (BatchN (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_110[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_103 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           batch_normalization_103[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
average_pooling2d_23 (AveragePo (None, 32, 32, 64)   0           activation_103[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_111 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 128)  73856       average_pooling2d_23[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_104 (BatchN (None, 32, 32, 128)  512         conv2d_111[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_104 (Activation)     (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           batch_normalization_104[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_112 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 128)  147584      activation_104[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_105 (BatchN (None, 32, 32, 128)  512         conv2d_112[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_105 (Activation)     (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           batch_normalization_105[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_21 (Conv2DTran (None, 64, 64, 64)   32832       activation_105[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_21 (Concatenate)    (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           conv2d_transpose_21[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_103[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_113 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   73792       concatenate_21[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_106 (BatchN (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_113[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_106 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           batch_normalization_106[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_114 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   36928       activation_106[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_107 (BatchN (None, 64, 64, 64)   256         conv2d_114[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_107 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           batch_normalization_107[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_22 (Conv2DTran (None, 128, 128, 32) 8224        activation_107[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_22 (Concatenate)    (None, 128, 128, 64) 0           conv2d_transpose_22[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_101[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_115 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 32) 18464       concatenate_22[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_108 (BatchN (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_115[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_108 (Activation)     (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_108[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_116 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        activation_108[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_109 (BatchN (None, 128, 128, 32) 128         conv2d_116[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_109 (Activation)     (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           batch_normalization_109[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_23 (Conv2DTran (None, 256, 256, 16) 2064        activation_109[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_23 (Concatenate)    (None, 256, 256, 32) 0           conv2d_transpose_23[0][0]        
                                                                 activation_99[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_117 (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 16) 4624        concatenate_23[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_110 (BatchN (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_117[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_110 (Activation)     (None, 256, 256, 16) 0           batch_normalization_110[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_118 (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 16) 3856        activation_110[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_111 (BatchN (None, 256, 256, 16) 64          conv2d_118[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_111 (Activation)     (None, 256, 256, 16) 0           batch_normalization_111[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_119 (Conv2D)             (None, 256, 256, 2)  34          activation_111[0][0]
```

Model code for first conv block

```
    padding = 'same'
    filter = (3,3)
    inputs = Input((256, 256, 2))
    k_init = 'he_normal'
    activate = 'tanh'
    
    c1 = Conv2D(16 * factor, filter, kernel_initializer = k_init, padding = padding) (inputs)
    c1 = Activation(activate) (c1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out where the error was.

My custom generator was returning an array of `(batch_size, 256, 512, 1)` rather than `(batch_size, 256, 256, 2)`. Once I corrected this, the network proceeds to training on the data